# jQuery - How to know if selector should have a # or . or anything like that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am learning jQuery and a few of the problems in my class have been having me do selector practice.

This is probably hella basic, but how do I know if that specific HTML or CSS element I'm selecting requires it to be `$('#element')` or `$('.element')` instead of just `$('element')`?

Comment: `#` is used to find elements by id and `.` by class. You can use `$(element)` to get elements by type: e.g `$('input')`, will return every document input element.

Comment: W3Schools is a good resource for learning all this stuff: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. I feel like that was explained to me and I just forgot it!

Comment: Just an addidion: `$(element)` would be to use a variable `element` which would hold a string like `#someId` or `.someClass`. You can even do concatenation like `$("#"+myVariable)`.... To target tag names, that is between quotes like : `$('input')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery (and the DOM functions `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`) are using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to select elements from the DOM.

So basically you look at (an) HTML element(s) and try to find something that identifies the element(s), for instance if you want one particular button:

```
<button id="login">Login</button>
```

You can use its `id`. IDs are by definition unique on the page, so you'll always get that button (or nothing if the ID is different or the button doesn't exist). The "id" selector is a `#` in front of the actual id, so you'd use `#login` here.

But what if you want to select multiple items that are similar? For instance:

```
<li class="menu-item">Home</li>
<li class="menu-item">Shop</li>
<li class="menu-button">Logout</li>
```

What if you want the all the `menu-item` elements, but not the `menu-button`?
This time you can use their `class` attribute. The class selector is prefixed with a `.`, so you'd use `.menu-item` to select those two elements.

There are many other elements and CSS has quite a bit of syntax. Here are a few examples:

- You can select by the element's tagname: `button` selects all `<button>` elements
- You can select by any attribute: `button[disabled]` selects all buttons with a `disabled` attribute like `<button disabled>n/a</button>`
- You can select based on their parent: `li img` selects all the images that are directly embedded in a `<li>` element

I highly recommend reading the MDN article for more information.